# PHP decryption from JS breaks on longer values

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

When I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a short word with several characters the following code does work. However if I try that with: `gmdv4hwHN7SrHwEhX0Sb6dskWkVezAUlmjTvHOV6QSAySI8pOrOsPrQoYVQpWP7j` It's like there's a max amount of characters. How do I resolve this issue?

JS

```js
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")

var message = 'gmdv4hwHN7SrHwEhX0Sb6dskWkVezAUlmjTvHOV6QSAySI8pOrOsPrQoYVQpWP7j';
var key = '59b6ab45d379b89d794c87b74a511';
var iv = '0aaff094b6bc297a';

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    message,
    CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key),
    { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv) }
).toString()
```

Output: `rQAT7R3TJUU+iLIzY+MNpoer7/br60oQrxo2O7BmI0b/O668bT7L5/cJUQbAFFDcwX4+8g3kjem6pCMGU7u9srVM7yauPmw8lcW9IiWSrbg=`

PHP

```php
<?php
$ciphertext = "rQAT7R3TJUU+iLIzY+MNpoer7/br60oQrxo2O7BmI0b/O668bT7L5/cJUQbAFFDcwX4+8g3kjem6pCMGU7u9srVM7yauPmw8lcW9IiWSrbg=";
$key = '59b6ab45d379b89d794c87b74a511';
$iv = '0aaff094b6bc297a';

var_dump (\openssl_decrypt(
    base64_decode($ciphertext),
    'aes-256-cbc',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $iv
));
```

Output: `bool(false)`

Comment: There is no limit, I can't reproduce the problem either (using `gmdv...` as plaintext and my own key and IV). Your question lacks a complete example for a repro: plaintext, key, IV, ciphertext.

Comment: @Topaco I have adjusted my original message to include the key and iv. The input message should be plaintext.

Comment: Key and IV are invalid. Both CryptoJS and PHP perform (different) corrections for invalid values. So use valid data and then check the results again. The CryptoJS code hex decodes key and IV, so the key must be 64 hex digits / 32 bytes in size for AES-256 (32 hex digits / 16 bytes for AES-128) and the IV 32 hex digits / 16 bytes for AES. In the PHP code the hex decoding of key and IV with `hex2bin()` is missing. Also, the PHP code must specify the algorithm _consistently_ (`aes-256-cbc` or `aes-128-cbc`, depending on the key size).

Comment: And, always define parameters instead of using the default ones. This is good programming practice for secuirty programmers.

Comment: @kelalaka what do you mean with using parameters instead of using the default ones?

Comment: For testing purposes, a key of the correct length is enough, i.e. consisting of the correct number of hex digits (see my last comment). Beyond testing, a key can be e.g. randomly generated or derived from a password using a key derivation function such as PBKDF2. The IV is usually randomly generated for each encryption. It is not secret and is passed along with the ciphertext ( typically concatenated).

Comment: Can you say which mode of operation JS is using as default? CBC, CTR, GCM? What if one day the default changes? As you see this is a good practice.